# Stream OpenCV Video Capture to flask server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

Greeting,
I was working on a drone project, I wanted to take stream from my drone process it on my laptop and give a command based on processing, I was using the flask framework from the same.

Currently, as the first step I want to take the stream from drone and PUT it to the flask server and view it on the flask website, not doing the processing part right now.

I PUT the video to server after compressing it into jpg and using base 64 to encode it and then finally use `json.dumps()` and then `requests.put()` it.

On the server side in flask server program I get its using `request.json`, use `json.loads()`, but I am not clear what to do next.

I am not experienced enough with flask, web development and with limited experience and knowledge made the programs, but it returns **error 405** on the flask program.

Here are the programs

flask server

```
import base64
import json

from flask import Flask, make_response, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


def getFrames(img):
    pass


@app.route('/video', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def video():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        load = json.loads(request.json)
        imdata = base64.b64decode(load['image'])
        respose = make_response(imdata.tobytes())
        return respose


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/cmd')
def cmd():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Video Stream</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Live Stream
    </h1>
    <div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video') }}" width="50%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

drone program

```
import base64
import json
import requests
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

ip = ''                   #url returned by the flask program

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("OUTPUT", img)
    _, imdata = cv2.imencode('.JPG', img)
    jStr = json.dumps({"image": base64.b64encode(imdata).decode('ascii')})
    requests.put(url=(ip + '/video'), data=jStr)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
```

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: NO! do **not** encode to base64! HTTP is perfectly capable of transferring binary data. and **do not** do any JSON!

Comment: you should send `jpg` without `base64` and `json` - it will be much smaller.

Comment: you define `/video` with `methods=['POST', 'GET']` but you send with `PUT` - it will not get it - you would need `methods=['POST', 'GET', "PUT"]` or you should use `post()` instead of `put()`

Comment: your `/video` works in wrong way - it get image from dron and send this image back to drone. You should get image from drone and save in file or keep in global variable. And you should use `if request.method == 'GET'` to send this image to other users (which load  HTML with `<img src"/video">`. But this may send it as single static image. To send it as stream it may need to send it as `mjpeg` (`motion-jpeg`) and it may need to create generator. You can see this in some examples which show how to stream local webcam in Flask.

Comment: [Video Streaming with Flask - miguelgrinberg.com](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)

Comment: it may be simpler if drone will send image to `/upload` and `/video` will send image only to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert to `base64` and use JSON. it can be simpler and faster to send JPG directly as raw bytes

And to make it simpler I would use `/upload` to send image from drone to server, and `/video` to send image to users.

```
import requests
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()

    if success:    
        cv2.imshow("OUTPUT", img)
        
         _, imdata = cv2.imencode('.JPG', img)

        print('.', end='', flush=True)

        requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload', data=imdata.tobytes())
    
    # 40ms = 25 frames per second (1000ms/40ms), 
    # 1000ms = 1 frame per second (1000ms/1000ms)
    # but this will work only when `imshow()` is used.
    # Without `imshow()` it will need `time.sleep(0.04)` or `time.sleep(1)`

    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:  # 40ms = 25 frames per second (1000ms/40ms) 
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Now flask. This part is not complete.

It gets image from drone and keep in global variable. And when user open page then it loads single image from `/video`

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

frame = None   # global variable to keep single JPG

@app.route('/upload', methods=['PUT'])
def upload():
    global frame
    
    # keep jpg data in global variable
    frame = request.data
    
    return "OK"

@app.route('/video')
def video():
    if frame:
        return make_response(frame)
    else:
        return ""

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'image:<br><img src="/video">'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

At this moment it can display only one static image. It needs to send it as `motion-jpeg`

---

**EDIT:**

Version which sends `motion-jpeg` so you see video.

It works correctly with `Chrome`, `Microsoft Edge` and `Brave` (all use chrome engine).

Problem makes `Firefox`. It hangs and tries to load image all time. I don't know what is the real problem but if I add `time.sleep()` then it can solve problem.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template_string, request
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

frame = None   # global variable to keep single JPG, 
               # at start you could assign bytes from empty JPG

@app.route('/upload', methods=['PUT'])
def upload():
    global frame
    
    # keep jpg data in global variable
    frame = request.data
    
    return "OK"

def gen():
    while True:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n'
               b'\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        time.sleep(0.04) # my Firefox needs some time to display image / Chrome displays image without it 
                         # 0.04s = 40ms = 25 frames per second 

        
@app.route('/video')
def video():
    if frame:
        # if you use `boundary=other_name` then you have to yield `b--other_name\r\n`
        return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    else:
        return ""

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'image:<br><img src="/video">'
    #return render_template_string('image:<br><img src="{{ url_for("video") }}">')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)#, use_reloader=False)
```

---

Server may runs users in separated threads on processes and sometimes it may not share `frame` between users. If I use `use_reloader=False` then I can stop sending to `/upload` and this stops video in browser, and later I can start again sending to `/upload` and browser again displays stream (without reloading page). Without `use_reloader=False` browser doesn't restart video and it needs to reload page. Maybe it will need to use `flask.g` to keep frame. Or `/upload` will have to save frame in file or database and `/video` will have to read frame from file or database.

Comment: I added version which send `motion-jpeg` and browser show it as video stream.

Comment: I know writing thanks needs to be avoided, but thanks dude you really made my month.